# React app on gh pages showing 404s for static files

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I know there have been a lot of questions for this topic but I've tried everything and still no luck.

I have this in my `index.js` file

```
const routing = (
  <HashRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/year_2019" render={(props) => <Year {...props} year={`2019`} />} />
      <Route path="/year_2018" render={(props) => <Year {...props} year={`2018`} />} />
      <Route path="/year_2017" render={(props) => <Year {...props} year={`2017`} />} />
      <Route path="/year_2016" render={(props) => <Year {...props} year={`2016`} />} />
      <Route path="/decade" render={(props) => <Year {...props} year={`Decade`} />} />
      <Route path="/ShowAlbums" component={ShowAlbums} />
      <Route path="/ShowSongs" component={ShowSongs} />
      <Route path="/collage" component={Collage} />
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have this in my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "albums-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://mrkerr.github.io/react-music",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.6.13",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^3.0.3",
    "react-typed": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and I have this in my `index.html`

```
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

I run `npm run deploy` and go to https://mrkerr.github.io/react-music/ and it loads the `index.html` but gives 404s for the `manifest.json` and says `net::ERR_ABORTED 404` for the `main.chunk.js`. I'm not sure what else to try, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your asset links are resolving to an incorrect URL. Specifically there is an extra `mrkerr` in the path to the assets which is not exactly where they are located.

For the manifest.json specifically, the browser is trying to download 
`https://mrkerr.github.io/mrkerr/react-music/manifest.json` instead of
`https://mrkerr.github.io/react-music/manifest.json`

I think the solution is to change your "homepage" in the package.json to `"homepage": "https://mrkerr.github.io/react-music"`.

There might also be another configuration option that is setting the `PUBLIC_URL` variable incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually just tried changing my homepage and still no luck. I've updated my post with my entire ```package.json``` file.

Comment: Wait I got it to work! I removed the ```%PUBLIC_URL%``` from the manifest link in my ```index.html```